# How draw wireframe of a 3D model in android application using openGl es 1.1

Tags: java, android, mobile, opengl-es, 3d

I have an android application for viewing 3D models. I could draw 3D models in shaded mode. But unable to draw it in wireframe mode. Please tell how to do this?

I have all the vertices in an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drawing in *wireframe* mode should only require *one* change in your current code. That is to switch the polygon mode to `GL_LINES` or `GL_LINE_STRIP`, in the `glDrawElements()`/`glDrawArrays()` call.

Comment: I found GL_LINE_LOOP to work better (it renders all the edges of the triangles)